# How to convert one time format to another in javascript using moment.tz?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I have tried various methods but I'm unable to convert date like `1640638800` to `2022-11-27 16:00:00 America/New_York` timezone format in javascript using `moment.tz`.

My current code was like

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
var date= new Date(0);
date.setUTCSeconds(1640638800);
moment.tz(date.getFullYear()+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getDay() + " 10:00:00", "America/New_York");
```

Comment: Are you sure you're expecting the output to be 2022-11-27 16:00:00? This looks like a December 2021 date

Answer (score 1):

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

// Unix Timestamp (milliseconds)
const ts = 1640638800 * 1000 

// Parse as timezoned moment
const m = moment.tz(ts, "America/New_York")

// Format moment to string
const formatted = m.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

console.log(formatted) // '2021-12-27 16:00:00'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.